# Good C++ solutions to the "Bring all the zeros to the back of the array" interview challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm

I had an interview for a Jr. development job and he asked me to write a procedure that takes an array of ints and shoves the zeroes to the back. Here are the constraints (which he didn't tell me at the beginning .... As often happens in programming interviews, I learned the constraints of the problem while I solved it lol):

- Have to do it in-place; no creating temporary arrays, new arrays, etc.
- Don't have to preserve the order of the nonzero numbers (I wish he would've told me this at the beginning)

Setup:

```
int arr[] = {0, -2, 4, 0, 19, 69}; 
/* Transform arr to {-2, 4, 19, 69, 0, 0} or {69, 4, -2, 19, 0, 0} 
   or anything that pushes all the nonzeros to the back and keeps
   all the nonzeros in front */
```

My answer:

```
bool f (int a, int b) {return a == 0;}
std::sort(arr, arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int), f);
```

What are some other good answers?

Comment: I think your answer is great. What did the interviewer say?

Comment: "I want to put stuff over on this side, and the other stuff on this side."  That is `std::partition`, hands down.  See my answer.

Comment: Your call to `std::sort` is invalid, because your comparison function does not establish a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Comment: This can easily be done in `O(n)` without any use of `std` routines, so the only thing that would bother me is whether `std::sort` (or `std::partition`, as suggested in one of the comments above) can guarantee this as worst-case complexity.

Comment: @barakmanos: `std::partition` can, and does guarantee O(n).

Comment: Smartass Answer: Overwrite every entry in the array with 0. This does not violate the constraints listed. `O(n)` algorithm.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe the interviewer was looking for this answer:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::partition(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int n) { return n != 0; });
```

If the order needs to be preserved, then `std::stable_partition` should be used:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::stable_partition(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int n) { return n != 0; });
```

For pre C++11:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::partition(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int), 
               std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<int>(), 0));
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/jpCOR3)

Basically, if the situation is that you need to move items that satisfy a condition to "one side" of a container, then the partition algorithm functions should be high up on the list of solutions to choose (if not **the** solution to use).

Comment: Isn't `partition` still O(NlogN)?

Comment: @JonathanMee - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition  For stable_partition, it becomes logarithmic in the worst case.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition

Comment: In the circumstance of an interview, it might be better to write the lambda as `[](const int &n){return n!=0;}` or perhaps even `[](const int &n)->bool{return n;}`, while being prepared to talk about the relative merits of `const int &` versus just `int`.  In either case, one doesn't need to capture any variables.

Comment: This is the clearest way.  OTOH, since `std::partition()` is implemented in terms of swaps, it does a constant factor's worth of unnecessary copying around.

Comment: @j_random_hacker code for clarity before optimality. It is good to know where cpu cycles might be hiding though.

Comment: @Edward - Thanks.  That reference is a bad habit.  I removed it from the lambda.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Man I totally misunderstood what `std::partition` was doing, it's O(N)! This is the best solution +1.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So I checked out the implementation of `std::partition` and it uses a `std::swap`. Which makes sense for most implementations. The only way my solution is avoiding that is that I know the value will be 0, so I don't need to store the old value to swap.

Answer (score 2):

An approach that sorts is O(N*Log<sub>2</sub>N). There is a linear solution that goes like this:

- Set up two pointers - `readPtr` and `writePtr`, initially pointing to the beginning of the array
- Make a loop that walks `readPtr` up the array to the end. If `*readPtr` is not zero, copy to `*writePtr`, and advance both pointers; otherwise, advance only `readPtr`.
- Once `readPtr` is at the end of the array, walk `writePtr` to the end of the array, while writing zeros to the remaining elements.

Comment: There are even fewer writes needed if you do the following: Start `readPtr` at the end and walk it backwards until it hits a nonzero element or `writePtr` (which starts out at the start as before).  If `readPtr` hits `writePtr`, you're finished.  Otherwise it hit a nonzero element, so walk `writePtr` forwards until it hits a zero element or `readPtr`.  If it hits `readPtr` then you're finished.  Otherwise it hit a zero element, so set it to `*readPtr`, set `*writePtr` to zero, and repeat.  Only the "out-of-position" zeroes and nonzeroes need to be copied this way.

Comment: This sounds a lot like `std::remove` followed by `std::fill`.

Answer (score 0):

This is O(n) so it may be what he's looking for:

```
auto arrBegin = begin(arr);
const auto arrEnd = end(arr);

for(int i = 0; arrBegin < arrEnd - i; ++arrBegin){
    if(*arrBegin == 0){
        i++;
        *arrBegin = *(arrEnd - i);
    }
}
std::fill(arrBegin, arrEnd, 0);
```