# C++ New Order for Structure Array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, structure

I have a structure array, where each structure has an id (int) and an value called aktiv (boolean).
I want to pass the structure array to a function which sorts the structure.
The structures in the array with an aktiv value of 0 (false) should be at the end of my array.

I thought i create an second array where i save my values temporarly and then put everything from the second array again in the first, but it work. What am i doing wrong or what should i change. Thanks in advance. My code:

```
void naende(Item itf[], int dim) { 
Item* temp_arr = new Item[dim]{};
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    if (itf[i].aktiv == 0) {
        temp_arr[dim - i].id = itf[i].id;
        temp_arr[dim - i].aktiv = itf[i].aktiv;
        //cout << temp_arr[i].id << endl;
    }
    else if (itf[i].aktiv == 1) {
        temp_arr[temp].id = itf[i].id;
        temp_arr[temp].aktiv = itf[i].aktiv;
        temp++;
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
    itf[j] = temp_arr[j];
}
}
```

Comment: please create a [mre]

Comment: other than items with `aktiv == false` going to the end is there any other criteria? E.g. does the sort needs to be stable? for `aktiv == true` do you sort by other criteria? Does that criteria apply to `aktiv == false`?

Comment: *The structures in the array with an aktiv value of 0 (false) should be at the end of my array.* -- There is a function that does this work already.  It's called [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)

Comment: I should create one by myself, its a previous exam exercise

Comment: @letstrythisone44 Your question asks:  *What am i doing wrong or what should i change* -- It makes no mention of what you can or cannot use.  The solution is a single line of code calling `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition`.  So you can investigate how those functions work, or please clarify everything you say you can't use.  Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003664/good-c-solutions-to-the-bring-all-the-zeros-to-the-back-of-the-array-intervi/27003708#27003708) shows usage of the functions I mentioned.

Comment: I posted an answer, showing all the approaches except for a home-made stable partition.   But if you look at your code, you dynamically allocate for a `temp_arr`, but this is totally unnecessary.  Not only that, your code leaks memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok but i still cant use it, sorry that i didn't mention it in my post, i didn't know std::partition exists now that i know it still dosen't matter, so how should i post it from the beginning?

Comment: Leave the code alone and simply update the requirements.  Also see the solution and understand how it works.  All you need is to swap items at the correct time -- there isn't any need for dynamic allocation.  There maybe a need for the stable version to dynamically allocate a temporary buffer, but you didn't mention that the items need to keep their relative order.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i can't use any std except for cout, so all of the awnsers are right, but don't help me with the problem im facing. I can't use swap either and i need a dynamic allocation becuase the value im passing could change, depending on what i hand over to the function, or am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: You are misunderstanding one principle of good design -- a function should be responsible for one thing.  The function I wrote does one thing -- move the 0's to the back -- that's it.  As far as `swap` -- it isn't difficult to write your own `swap` -- all `std::swap` does is exchange the items.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i honestly don't quite get it, i know your awnser is perfect and i understand what you are doing but why is my code not working. I create a second temporary array just to store the data of the first array in there, could you maybe explain why this isnt working?

Comment: First, your code leaks memory.  That's one reason why it doesn't work.  Second is that your "swaps" are not done correct in that `dim` has to be decremented, which you failed to do when you realize you need to do a swap.  In short, it is logically wrong -- right side should only decrement on a swap, and left side should only increment if the item is in the right position.  Better to scrub what you were thinking of, and just look at the correct solution -- sometimes things are better done by thinking different than trying to understand a (very) broken attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you've posted, if the goal is to move all `aktiv` items that are 0 to the back of the array, then [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) can be used.

```
#include <algorithm>

void naende(Item itf[], int dim) 
{ 
   std::partition(itf, itf + dim, [&](const Item& it) { return it.aktiv == 1; });
}
```

The code above places all `aktiv` entries equal to 1 to the left of the array, and all `aktiv` entries equal to 0 to the right of the array.

If the relative order needs to be maintained, then [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) can be used:

```
#include <algorithm>

void naende(Item itf[], int dim) 
{ 
   std::stable_partition(itf, itf + dim, [&](const Item& it) { return it.aktiv == 1; });
}
```

The point of the above code is to emphasize that there are STL algorithm or a set of STL algorithm functions that can be used to do a lot of work that would usually require a hand-coded solution (which would have to be debugged if there are errors).  Using the functions above, the STL algorithm functions do not fail if given valid parameters.

---

Now let's say you can't use `std::partition`, and order need not be preserved.  If this is the case, then the way this is accomplished can be to simply have two pointers, and call `std::swap` in a loop at strategic times.

The way it works is that you would have an index that goes forward in the array, and another index that starts at the end of the array and goes backwards.  The incrementing of the first index, the decrementing of the end index, and the calls to `std::swap` would be done this way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Item
{
    int id;
    int aktiv;
};

void naende(Item itf[], int dim)
{
    int leftpos = 0;
    int rightpos = dim - 1;
    while (leftpos < rightpos)
    {
        if (itf[leftpos].aktiv == 0)
        {
            std::swap(itf[leftpos], itf[rightpos]);
            --rightpos;
        }
        else
            ++leftpos;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Item item[] = { {1,1},{2,0},{34,0},{32,1},{12,0},{12,1},{21,1} };
    naende(item, 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        std::cout << item[i].id << " " << item[i].aktiv << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 1
21 1
12 1
32 1
12 0
34 0
2 0
```

We basically only go forward with the left index if we detect that the `aktiv` value is 1.  If it isn't `1`, then we put that item in the back by swapping with the back item, then we decrement the back item index.

For stable items, I will leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation without `std::partition`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Item {
    int id;
    bool aktiv;
};

//in-place swap
void swap(Item& left, Item& right) {
    left.aktiv ^= right.aktiv;
    right.aktiv ^= left.aktiv;
    left.aktiv ^= right.aktiv;
    left.id ^= right.id;
    right.id ^= left.id;
    left.id ^= right.id;
}

void naende(Item itf[], const size_t dim) {
    if (dim < 2) return;    //array is empty or has one single item, so do nothing
    Item temp = itf[0];     //init the temp to take the first item (adds only 1 more item in memory space)
    size_t rightSwapIndex = dim-1;  //index to put the checked item at the rightmost position
    size_t leftSwapIndex = 0;       //index to put the checked item at the leftmost position
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {  //consider exactly 'dim' cases (guarantees algorithm to be O(n) time)
        if (!temp.aktiv) {  //needs to moved to the rightmost position
            swap(temp, itf[rightSwapIndex--]);  //swap the temp with the last item; and move the rightSwapIndex to left by one
        } else {
            itf[leftSwapIndex] = temp;      //put the temp at the rightmost index (may have no effect but important!)
            temp = itf[++leftSwapIndex];    //take the next item to consider; and move the leftSwapIndex to right
        }
    }
}

void printDebug(Item array[], const size_t dim) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
        std::cout<<array[i].id<<"/"<<array[i].aktiv<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    //build some test array with a sample data
    size_t size = 10;
    Item array[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        array[i].id = i;
        array[i].aktiv = i%2;   //TODO: test with some other inits as well, like for ex. this one: array[i].aktiv = (i%3)%2;
    }

    //test the function naende()
    printDebug(array, size);    //print out the array before the call
    naende(array, size);        //call our cute function
    printDebug(array, size);    //print out the array after the call
}
```

Output:

```
0/0 1/1 2/0 3/1 4/0 5/1 6/0 7/1 8/0 9/1 
9/1 1/1 7/1 3/1 5/1 6/0 4/0 8/0 2/0 0/0
```

Another output with a different array init (see my comment line above with TODO:)

```
0/0 1/1 2/0 3/0 4/1 5/0 6/0 7/1 8/0 9/0 
7/1 1/1 4/1 3/0 5/0 6/0 2/0 8/0 9/0 0/0
```

Comment: `static Item temp;`  I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but whatever it is, this is not necessary.  You also make the many times fatal mistake of `using namespace std;` and calling `swap`.   So which `swap` will be used, yours, or `std::swap`?  Also, variable length arrays are not standard C++, yet you're using them.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenzie! I'll review my code and make an edit ;) But regarding to static I've explained in my comment in that line.

Comment: Introducing function static variables for no reason will make the code slower, not faster.  The compiler is now forced to check for multiple threads calling `swap`.  So you made a mole-hill into a mountain.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, why do you make such a generalised statement? In this case, that single static variable will be kept in memory during the entire execution of the program, and save time on deallocation (upon ending the scope of the swap() function) and reallocation of it on the next call. Why it should have a negative impact?

Comment: Function `static` variables now need to be checked for multithreaded access.  That is now the rule for C++ 11 and above.  By you adding that `static` variable, the compiler now has to generate code that does thread locking, checking, etc.  Yes, it is now that pervasive.  This is why trying to "beat the compiler" at the speed game by writing code you think is fast almost always fails.

Comment: BTW, the protection for function statics were to actually address race conditions in old C++ 98 and C++ 03 code.  So in a sense it was a good thing that function statics are now checked for MT access, because a lot of broken code just now magically works with C++11 just by recompiling with a newer compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I've edited my answer according to your comments. And I wonder which swap was called before? Correct me if I'm wrong, but my guess is that since std::swap() is generic, the compiler will not generate its overloaded version with the pair of parameters of type Item, hence there would be only 1 swap() function, i.e. my defined one.

Comment: [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is a templatized function.  Thus by using `using namespace std;`, you are basically calling `std::swap`.  That's why I mentioned that specifying `using namespace std;` and calling `swap` will have issues.

Comment: I think even the std::swap would do the work, but the question in my last comment was about the std::swap(Item&, Item&) not being generated at all, due to my definition. I mean UB is excluded in such a case. And I just tested with some logs, it was calling my own swap() function.

Answer (score 0):

your post is not clear, but you can try this :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    int active;
    int id;
};

void SortByStat(Item itf[], int dim)
{
    std::stable_partition(itf,itf + dim ,[](const Item &a){return a.active == 1;});

    //std::sort(itf, itf + dim, [](const Item &a, const Item &b) { return a.active < b.active; });
}

int main()
{
    Item arr[5] = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}};
    int size = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "id = " << arr[i].id << " => " << arr[i].active << endl;
    }

    cout << "After Sorting" << endl;

    SortByStat(arr, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "id = " << arr[i].id << " => " << arr[i].active << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting the array is already making its time complexity O(nlogn).

Comment: The OP is looking for partitioning.  Partitioning doesn't need sorting.  Yes, sorting will work, but it is less efficient.

Comment: make sense, Thank you.