# How to maintaining relative order of non-zero elements during array sorting?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Given an array nums, I am writing a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) 
    {
        const std::vector<int> v;
        int count = 0;
        int i;
        int n = nums.size();
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(nums[i]!=0)
            { v.push_back[count++]=nums[i];
            }
        }
        while(count<n)
        {
            v.push_back[count++]=0;
        }
        
    }
};
```

But I'm unable to figure out the following error:

```
Line 12: Char 17: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        { v.push_back[count++]=nums[i];
          ~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1184:7: note: possible target for call
  push_back(const value_type& __x)
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1200:7: note: possible target for call
  push_back(value_type&& __x)
  ^
```

Comment: Modifying `v` is not allowed because it is declared as `const`.

Comment: `push_back` is a function. Not really sure what you're trying to do. Maybe `v.push_back(nums[i]);`? Once you remove the const that is.

Comment: This is a one-line solution using [std::stable_partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003664/good-c-solutions-to-the-bring-all-the-zeros-to-the-back-of-the-array-intervi)

Comment: I'm sure you have to do it "in-place", without the help of another vector

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot modify objects declared as `const`.
- `push_back` is a function and your usage is wrong.

The process can be done by using [`std::remove`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/remove.html) to remove `0`s and [`std::fill`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/fill.html) to put `0`s to the space after the vector with `0`s removed.

```
#include <algorithm>

class Solution {
public:
    void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) 
    {
        vector<int>::iterator pos = std::remove(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);
        std::fill(pos, nums.end(), 0);
    }
};
```