# partial_sort not working correctly for vector

Tags: c++, vector

Trying to solve 'move zeros' question. I have to shift all zeros of vector at last and then all other numbers need to be arranged in ascending order.

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
        int position = nums.size()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(nums[i]==0 && nums[position]!=0 && position>=i){
                int temp=nums[i];
                nums[i]=nums[position];
                nums[position]=temp;
                
                position-=1;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
                cout<<nums[i]<<" ";
                
            }
            
            cout<<endl;
        }
        std::partial_sort(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+position, nums.end());
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: After moving the zeros, just call `std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.begin() + position);`. In general, algorithms apply to the range that you pass in, in this case, `[nums.begin() .. enums.begin() + position)`.  **You** know that you're only passing in part of the contents of the vector, but the algorithm doesn't care.

Comment: Looks like it needs to be `std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.begin() + position + 1);` so the end is one past the range.

Comment: [Solution already given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003664/good-c-solutions-to-the-bring-all-the-zeros-to-the-back-of-the-array-intervi/27003708#27003708).  Use `std::partition` -- the solution becomes a single line of code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at what [`std::partial_sort()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) does:

> Rearranges elements such that the range `[first, middle)` contains the sorted `middle - first` smallest elements in the range `[first, last)`.

In other words, the partitioning you did is ignored.

There are a few alternatives:

1. [`std::sort()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) it all, and [`std::rotate()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) the zeroes to the end.
2. Sort it all with a custom comparator considering zero the biggest value.
3. [`std::partition()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) the range so zeroes are at the end, and then sort the front.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) and then `std::sort`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>   

void moveZeroes(std::vector<int>& nums) 
{
    // Partition by placing zeros on the right.  Returns the partition point
    auto iter = std::partition(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&](int n) 
                              { return n != 0; });    

    // Now sort the items at the left of the partition.  
    std::sort(nums.begin(), iter);
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> nums = {0,1,0,3,12};
   moveZeroes(nums);
   for (auto i : nums)
     std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 3 12 0 0
```

The first step is to partition the elements.  The return value for `std::partition` will be an iterator pointing to the partition point.

The last step is to now sort all of the items at the left of the partition, since the zeros were placed on the right of the partition.

Comment: The lambda could be replace by C++20 [`std::identity`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity), as there is no need to use `!= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
  std::sort(begin(nums),end(nums),[](int x,int y){if(!x)return false;if(!y)return true; return x<y;});
}
```

seems simpler.

Comment: Shouldn't that rather be: `return !x ? !!x : !y ? !y : x < y;` or better yet `return x && (x < y || !y);`? You return the wrong result for both zero.

Comment: @dep swapped x and y tests, fixed it.