# n is 0 after passing it as an argument to the function, What seems to be the problem here?

Tags: c++, sorting

Here the question is to put all the **zeroes to the end of the array.**
I've written the code below, but after passing `(arr, n)` to the `pushzero()` function, when I try to print the array, it does nothing, and the value of `n` changes to zero after calling the `pushzero()` function.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void pushzero(int arr[], int n) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == 0) {
                swap(arr[j+1], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 2, 6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 8, 0 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " " << "\n";
    }
    pushzero(arr, n);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // n is 0 here
        cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where `j<i+1` did you mean `j<i` ?

Comment: Please don't tag c in c++ questions

Comment: it's i+1, as I'm comparing every element with their adjacent ones. @WeatherVane

Comment: You are writing outside the array bounds with `swap(arr[j+1], arr[j]);`

Comment: You have a buffer overflow. https://godbolt.org/z/9T76PxqTT

Comment: so, i change it to j<n-i-1, but Why is it so that the value of n becomes 0 after calling the function. @WeatherVane

Comment: It isn't `i+1`, otherwise you will end up swapping `arr[n], arr[n-1]`, which is out of bounds, and will overwrite the next variable after `arr[]`. which is, guess what? `n`. It should be `j < i`.

Comment: You are not comparing every element with the adjacent one, you are comparing with 0. You are *swapping* with the adjacent element, and if `[j]` is the last element then you'll break something. "Why is it so that the value of n becomes 0 after calling the function."

Comment: You don't require two for loops for this.

Comment: @UTKARSHLUCIFER *put all the zeroes to the end of the array* -- [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003664/good-c-solutions-to-the-bring-all-the-zeros-to-the-back-of-the-array-intervi/27003708#27003708).  No loop is required. Basically, this is a 1-line solution using `std::partition`.

Comment: @Avinash Provide me a solution using one loop.

Comment: @UTKARSHLUCIFER -- [Solution using std::stable_partition](https://godbolt.org/z/9ncG44jzE).  Also, it seems you may have gotten this question from one of those "competitive coding" websites.  Well, the one-line solution is more "competitive" than what you are trying to do.  The answer is a one-liner (less typing), and it works.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by using 0 as a pivot element and whenever you see a non zero element you will swap it with the pivot element. So all the non zero element will come at the beginning.

```
void pushzero(int arr[], int n) {  
    int j =0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        if(arr[i] != 0) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oMdxfdWjG

Comment: should not `i` start with 1? otherwise if `arr[0]` is non-zero, it gets swapped with itself. You can avoid an extra loop by starting with 1.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was about why `n` became zero.

Comment: @Aamir No it shouldn't. What you're saying is possible if `arr[0]` is always equals to `0`

Answer (score 3):

The code has undefined behavior because the inner loop in `pushzero` iterates too far:

- in the last iteration of the outer loop of `pushzero`, `i` has the value `n - 1`
- the last iteration of the inner loop, `j` has the value `i`, hence `n - 1`,
- if the test `arr[j] == 0` is true, which will happen since there are multiple zeroes in the array, `swap` will be called to exchange the values of `arr[j]` and `arr[j+1]`, hence reading and modifying `arr[n]` which is beyond the end of the array.

This undefined behavior may have surprising consequences, such as the behavior you observe, possibly because `n` is stored in stack memory just after the array `arr`, an indication that you disabled optimisations.

Changing the loop test to `j < i` fixes the out of bounds access but does not achieve your goal. You should write `j < n - i - 1` for proper operation.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void pushzero(int arr[], int n) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == 0) {
                swap(arr[j+1], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 2, 6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 8, 0 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    pushzero(arr, n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The above implementation is suboptimal as it has **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** complexity. Below is a simpler one with linear execution time:

```
void pushzero(int arr[], int n) {   
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    while (j < n) {   
        arr[j++] = 0;
    }
}
```

Or using the `swap()` function with slightly more work:

```
void pushzero(int arr[], int n) {  
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[j++]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a more idiomatic C++ solution, as suggested by *@PaulMcKenzie*:

```
#include <algorithm>

void pushzero(int arr[], int len) {   
    std::stable_partition(arr, arr + len, [](int n) { return n != 0; });
}
```

Comment: Changing it to j<i don't help. Could you rectify and post a correct solution of it considering the methods I applied.

Comment: @UTKARSHLUCIFER Define 'doesn't help'. It should cure `n` becoming zero at least, which is what you actually asked about.