# why is my comparator function not working?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, comparator

I have an array with elements as `[0, 1, 0, 3, 12]`. I want to shift all the zeros to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements. After shifting the array should look like this `[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]`. So to do this I wrote the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

bool cmp(int a, int b){
    if (a == 0) {
        return a > b;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 0, 3, 12};
    sort(arr, arr + 5, cmp);
    for (int i: arr) {
        cout << i;
    }
}
```

I wrote this code thinking that by returning `false` whenever zero is placed before a non-zero element `i` can swap the elements but this code gives the output as `[12, 3, 1, 0, 0]` i.e it just sorted the elements in descending order. Can anyone explain me why my comparator function does not working? Can I use comparator function to do this?

Comment: You're telling the sort function that 12<3 and 12<1 and 3<1 and 3<12 and 1<12 and 1<3. Depending on which way around it happens to compare the numbers (3<1 vs 1<3) you are telling it the wrong thing.

Comment: [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) does all of what you are asking for.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003664/good-c-solutions-to-the-bring-all-the-zeros-to-the-back-of-the-array-intervi/27003708#27003708).

Comment: [Using stable_partition](https://godbolt.org/z/PzYxTecEY).  Also, that `bits` header should not be used.  Use the proper headers, i.e. `<algorithm>`, `<iostream>`.

Comment: `cmp(0, -1)` returns `true`, but `cmp(-1, 0)` also returns `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparator you pass to `std::sort` needs to be a [strict weak order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). In particular, you need `cmp(x, x) = false` for the same value, and at most one of `cmp(x, y)` and `cmp(y, x)` to be true (which is not true for `cmp(1, 2) == cmp(2, 1) == true`)

What you want in your order is for all elements to be equivalent, except 0 which is greater than all other elements. This can be done with a function like this:

```cpp
bool cmp(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0) {
        if (b == 0) return false;  // equal
        return false;  // a is greater
    }
    if (b == 0) return true;  // `a < 0`? True, since 0 is the greatest element
    return false;  // All other elements are equivalent, not less than
}

// Simplified to
bool cmp(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 && a != 0;
}
```

And then you want to use [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) to preserve the order of the equivalent elements.

---

However, sorting isn't the best approach here. You can simply move all the non-zero elements forward, then fill in the back space with 0s:

```cpp
void move_zeroes_to_back(int* begin, int* end) {
    int* nonzero_begin = begin;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (*begin != 0) *nonzero_begin++ = *begin;
        // else Don't move zero values forward
    }
    // Fill in the rest
    for (; nonzero_begin != end; ++nonzero_begin) {
        *nonzero_begin = 0;
    }
}
```

Where the first part of this algorithm is what [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) does:

```cpp
void move_zeroes_to_back(int* begin, int* end) {
    int* nonzero_end = std::remove(begin, end, 0);  // Remove all zero values
    std::fill(nonzero_end, end, 0);  // Replace removed zero values at the end
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! i really needed someone to explain the requirements. but i want to know why does the comparator function not work for this input: [-58305,-22022,0,0,0,0,0,-76070,42820,48119,0,95708,-91393,60044,0,-34562,0,-88974]. it doesn't seem to preserve the order of the non zero elements for some reason...

Comment: It seems to work fine here: <https://godbolt.org/z/4r7oYYKME>. Make sure you're using `std::stable_sort` to preserve the order of the equivalent elements

Comment: In your first example you return false if b == 0 and also otherwise. Is this a typo or intended?

Comment: @BenjaminBuch It's the "everything is expanded out" version. It corresponds to `a != 0` in the simplified version after (since `a==0`=>`return false`)

Answer (score 5):

Your comparison function does not satisfy the requirements  for comparison functions. For example if `cmp( a, b )` returns `true` then `cmp( b, a )` shall return `false`.

Instead of using the algorithm `std::sort` use algorithm `std::stable partition` as for example

```
    std::stable_partition( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), 
        []( const auto &x ) { return x != 0; } );
```

On the other hand, if non-zero elements are not ordered as for example

```
int arr[] = { 0, 3, 0, 12, 1 };
```

and you want to sort them then you can write the call of `std::sort` the following way

```
std::sort( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ),
    []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
    {
        return a != 0 && b != 0 ? a < b : a != 0;
    } );
```

Here is a demonstration function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 0,3,0,12,1 };
    //std::stable_partition( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), 
    //  []( const auto &x ) { return x != 0; } );

    std::sort( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ),
        []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
        {
            return a != 0 && b != 0 ? a < b : a != 0;
        } );

    for (int i : arr) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
1 3 12 0 0
```

Or if you like then instead of the lambda expression you can write a separate comparison functopm

```
bool cmp( int a, int b )
{
    return a != 0 && b != 0 ? a < b : a != 0;
}
```

In this case the call of `std::sort` will look like

```
std::sort( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), cmp );
```